# Can you use AVG() and PERCENTILE_DISC() functions together in a single Redshift query?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm having difficulty combining these two functions in to a single query, such as:

```
WITH time_values AS (
    SELECT
        (end_time - start_time) * 1.0 / 3600000000 AS num_hours
    FROM table
    WHERE
        end_time >= 1493596800000000
        AND start_time < 1493683200000000
)

SELECT
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num_hours) OVER() AS p25,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num_hours) OVER() AS p50,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num_hours) OVER() AS p80,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num_hours) OVER() AS p99,
    AVG(num_hours)
FROM time_values;
```

This returns `ERROR:  column "time_values.num_hours" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AVG()` can be both aggregate (requires grouping by some column) and window function (requires frame clause). The error appears because you use a window function `PERCENTILE` already and there is no frame clause for `AVG` function though it's not obvious. To use `AVG` in the same query you need to simulate the clause which will look like

```
AVG(num_hours) OVER ()
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up (is this a separate question?): so far my query returns multiple rows for each `var` with the same data. Is there a way to limit this to 1 return record per value of `var`?

Comment: right, it does since it's a window functions not aggregates... then you'll have to add `distinct` to your `select` and you're all set

Comment: Ah - this is great. Thanks!